# How to send photos to Chromecast?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, photos, chromecast

I have made a bunch of shiny photos with my Nexus 4 and now I want to watch them on my Chromecast. Trouble is that the standard photo application wants me to upload the photos to the cloud and then add them to an album.

Is there an easier way to watch my photo gallery on my Chromecast? A cloudfree solution that just shows all my photos on my device would work best.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of different apps you could try, each with varying amounts of features. A few specific examples:

- [Allcast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.cast) - Also supports other devices like Roku and Xbox. Casts pretty much any kind of media.
- [Dayframe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cloudtv.dayframe) - Intended mostly for casting pictures as a slideshow/digital frame.
- [PhotoCast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ostec.photocast) - Can display photos in a few different styles, including one that plots the location of geotagged images on a map in the background.